# Android Studio can only copy so file to lib which name starts with "lib"

Tags: android-studio

I have libs in `jniLibs/armeabi-v7a` which like:

```
liba.so
libb.so
a.so
b.so
```

And after I install the apk, I can only have libxxx.so in `/data/app/myapp/lib/arm` which are:

```
liba.so
libb.so
```

The `a.so` and `b.so` is missing.

My question is: How can I pack a.so to apk?